# Modal Heyting Algebras

Tags: reference-request, modal-logic, intuitionistic-logic, heyting-algebra

Is there a standard way to add modal operators over a Heyting algebra -- as it was done e.g. by Johnstone and Tarski for Boolean algebras? Does this provide a semantics to some version of intuitionistic modal logic? Do you know any standard reference for this?